# Invalid hook call при работе с localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localstorage, импорт

Имеется 3 файла:

1. Основной компонент
2. Файл со стейтами, которые забиваются в локальное хранилище
3. Файл с функцией-ресетом для сброса этих самых стейтов в дефлотные значения

Я импотрирую файл со стейтами в основной компонент и всё ок, но когда я импортирую файл с функцией-ресетом, получаю ошибку "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. "

Почитал документацию по реакту, но понимания ошибки не пришло

1. Код первого файла

```
import React from 'react';
import { LocalStorage } from './components/localStorageList'
import { resetLocalStorage } from './components/resetLocalStorage'

function mainComponent() {

    const localState = LocalStorage(); // local storage keys
    const resetState = () => resetLocalStorage(); // reset local storate states

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => resetState()}>
                 {svgRefreshPage}
           </button>
       </div>
    )
}
```

2. Код второго файла

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useLocalStorageList = (key, defaultValue) => {
    const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
    const initial = stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : defaultValue;
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [key, value]);

    return [value, setValue];
};

//local storage keys
export const LocalStorage = () => {

    const [localStorageState, setLocalStorageState] = useLocalStorageList('Timer time', 1800)

    return {localStorageState, setLocalStorageState}
}
```

3. Код третьего файла

```
import { LocalStorage } from './localStorageList'

const localState = LocalStorage(); //local storage keys

export const resetLocalStorage = () => {

    localState.setTimerValue(1800)
}
```

[Ссылка на sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-galileo-r2t37?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: не, так это не работает. третий файл не нужен. Что вообще должен делать третий файл? И откуда в нем `setTimerValue` метод, если в других файлах этого метода нет

Comment: У меня очень много стейтов и для удобства я решил разнести их и функцию ресета по разным файлам, здесь в пример я привёл по одной строке. Да, не доглядел , что в третьем файле показал то, чего нет во втором, но на реальном коде всё есть )

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const localState = LocalStorage(); //local storage keys
> ```

Этот вызов кривой. Он вообще вне компонента.

Comment: Переместил внутрь компонента - помогло, но теперь эта же самая ошибка вылезла при нажатии на кнопку, которая должна ресетить стейты (обновил код первого файла)

Comment: @Miltosh, _но теперь эта же самая ошибка вылезла при нажатии_ - потому что там та же самая ошибка очевидно

Comment: @Grundy, Мне не очевидно. Вы имеете в виду, что во втором файле useLocalStorageList вынесен за экспортируемый компонент ? Я пробовал переносить его вовнутрь, но это не дало результата

Comment: @Miltosh, нет, у тебя та же самая строчка вызывается вне какой либо функции, как у тебя это было в main.js

Comment: @Grundy, спорим, что внутри хэндлера события?

Comment: @Qwertiy, что внутри хэндлера события? :)

Comment: @Grundy, вызывает эту штуку внутри хэндлера события. Потом перенёс хендлер куда-то, но естественно это не помогло.

Comment: @Miltosh, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KJxaFHotqI

Comment: @Qwertiy, так в третий файл очевидно :)

Comment: @Grundy, кажется, я не читал)

Comment: @Qwertiy, Спасибо за видео, но можно уточнить, какой конкретно хук здесь должен использоваться ? Потому что из вашей переписки я вообще ничего не понял

Comment: @Miltosh, по-моему, ты вообще их используешь неправильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Я для этого сюда и обратился, что бы помогли объяснить как правильно.

Добавил ссылку на sandbox

Answer (score 0):

У хуков есть ограничения, на то, где их можно вызывать:

1. непосредственно внутри функции компонента
2. непосредственно внутри другого хука

Также рекомендуют называть их начиная с `use`, эта договоренность позволяет реакту проверять правильность вызова и пользовательских хуков.

В коде в вопросе, вызов хука `LocalStorage` в третьем файле происходит вне компонента либо другого хука, отсюда и ошибки.

Кроме того, в данном случае нет смысла разделять действия над хранилищем на два файла, и достаточно просто объявить метод `reset` внутри `LocalStorage`, в этом случае код может выглядеть так:

```
export const LocalStorage = () => {
  const [localStorageState, setLocalStorageState] = useLocalStorageList(
    "State",
    "Default Value"
  );

  const resetLocalStorageState = () => {
    setLocalStorageState("Default Value");
  };

  return [localStorageState, setLocalStorageState, resetLocalStorageState];
};
```

И в использовании

```
function App() {
  const [value, update, reset] = LocalStorage(); // local storage keys

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={reset}>Refresh State to default</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => update("State was changed")}>Change State</button>
      <p>{value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Пример в песочнице: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-feather-1mtgg?file=/src/localState.jsx